# is it possible to run a unit test command in codesandbox

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I added a simple unit test file in codesandbox, this is the project link: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-cherry-z9of7?file=/package.json, then I want to use this command to run the unit test:

```
stanbul cover _mocha ./test/demo.js
```

but I found the console in codesandbox could not run any commands, no node, no npm, no yarn...... is it possible to run a command in codesandbox? is it possible to write a javascript unit test lib in codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out their docs : https://codesandbox.io/docs/tests

Comment: only support jest. I am using jasmine.@suppaGonzalo I tweak the file name end with .spec.js  so that the system could automatic treated as test .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).